# malloc: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed. OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

The code estimates the translation and rotation matrix of 2 sets of points using SVD.

```
vector<Point2f> ptOrigin(matchesNumber), ptTarget(matchesNumber);
Point2f ptCenterOrigin(0, 0), ptCenterTarget(0, 0);
Mat X(2, matchesNumber, CV_32F), Y(matchesNumber, 2, CV_32F);

for(int i = 0; i < matchesNumber; i++)
{
    X.at<double>(0, i) = ptOrigin[i].x - ptCenterOrigin.x;
    X.at<double>(1, i) = ptOrigin[i].y - ptCenterOrigin.y;
    Y.at<double>(i, 0) = ptTarget[i].x - ptCenterTarget.x;
    Y.at<double>(i, 1) = ptTarget[i].y - ptCenterTarget.y;
}
Mat S, w, u, vt;
S = X * Y;
SVD::compute(S, w, u, vt);
```

There is something wrong with this line: `S = X * Y;`. The error message is: malloc: *** error for object 0x10105f3f8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.

*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug.

I'm new to OpenCV, can someone help me with that? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the issue, but CV_32F should be accessed with float, not double.